# data type to store time with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I have to make an appointment system for doctors using MEAN stack. in my Schema I've to store the start time and end time of a slot. Mongoose has no data type to store time.What data type should I use to store time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the `timestamps` property to `true` when defining a Schema and mongoose will add a `createdAt` and `updatedAt` field for you. Mongoose will also update the `updatedAt` field for you when you do any update operation.

```
var schema = new Schema({
    // ... Schema properties
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps

Comment: why is this marked as the proper answer? This makes no sense at all

Comment: @JuanIgnacioMignacoFernández I'm curious as to why you think this makes no sense at all? It literally states what to do and what will happen after.

Comment: because he asked to store time, not timestamps, on top of that storing start time or end time for a slot time on an appointments app, has nothing to do with createAt/updatedAt of the record, that just for audit purposes

Comment: Is there any specific datatype for just only time instead of `date` where i can store time like this `10:12 pm` instead of `2021-06-22T21:30:34.736+00:00` ?

Answer (score 26):

The `Date` [schema type](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) of Mongoose represents not just a date, but a full date and time timestamp, so that would be the logical choice.

```
var slotSchema = new Schema({
    startTime: Date,
    endTime: Date,
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The Date object stores a specific moment down to the millisecond.

See: http://www.robertprice.co.uk/robblog/2011/05/javascript_date_time_and_node_js-shtml/

For more information on mongoose: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

Answer (score 1):

No direct solution for time only scenarios. Being forced to use Date isn't always applicable. Using type string with a custom validation using regex is what I decided to use.

```js
  classTiming: {
    type: String,
    validate: {
      validator: function (v) {
        if (!v) {
          return true;
        }
        return /([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]/.test(v);
      },
      message: (props) => `${props.value} is not valid time!`,
    },
  },
```

Time seems to be an ignored type. Whether its zod or joi, both needed a regex approach at the time of writing this:

```
  classTiming: z
    .string()
    .regex(/([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]/)
    .optional()
    .or(z.literal("")),
```

```
    classTiming: Joi.string()
      .regex(/([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]/)
      .empty(""),
```